# next/router: How to access referer from either Router or withRouter?

Tags: next.js

> import Router, { withRouter } from "next/router";

Is it possible to access a referer (previous url value) property from either Router.x or props.router.y?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not possible you will have to keep track of previously visited pages using a global state (redux, localStorage....)